# You have to tell who among them is the culprit

Tags: sentence-construction

> You have to tell who among them is the culprit.

I have ended this sentence with a full stop. Is it correct?

Comment: Do you think this might be a question because of the word "who"?

Comment: Similarly *"You have to tell which of them is the culprit."* is not a question.

Comment: It is a simple statement (an assertive sentence). You would end it with comma. So it is correct. _Who among them is the culprit?_ and _You have to tell who among them is the culprit._

Comment: tell needs an object: me, you, them, us, him or her. Unless tell is about being a tattletale.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant aspect of the syntax / orthography are just the same with ***who did it*** as with ***who among them is the culprit***, so let's look at some shortened alternatives...

> 1: You have to tell who did it.
> 2: You have to tell me who did it.
> 3: You have to say who did it.
> 4: You have to answer the question "Who did it?".

I think #1 above sounds "childish" - it reminds me of the construction *I'm going to tell **on** you* with unstated implied object *...tell **someone in authority about** you* (I'm going to inform against you).

The verb ***tell*** normally requires a direct object (the person something is told ***to***) as well as an optional indirect object (the information imparted). So we need ***me*** in #2 to make the construction natural - but if we use ***say*** instead of ***tell***, as in #3, we don't need to do this.

As regards the possibility of including a question mark, #4 is how ***I*** (BrE) would write it if I was going to include the actual question. Others might punctuate it differently, though<sup>1</sup>.

---

Note that in my shortened versions above, we have to use the pronoun ***who*** (because it directly refers to a *person*), but with OP's longer version many people (not *everyone*) would be quite happy to use ***which*** (as in [*Which among you is the captain?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22which%20among%20you%20is%20the%20captain%22)).

---

<sup>1</sup> Americans in particular are inclined *not* to write the "sentence-terminating" full stop *after* the closing quote mark of a verbatim reported speech question. Presumably, this is on the grounds that the question mark *before* that closing quote can perform "double duty" to terminate both the question *and* the enclosing sentence).

But I personally would normally include that final full stop as in my example #4, ***unless*** it was in the context of a reported speech interchange / dialogue, where the *next* "sentence" started with a quote-enclose utterance from another speaker. For example...

> *[A young man] said: 'Which of you is the suspect, please?' 'That's me,' Steve said.*

(Single or double quote marks, it's all the same.)